# Damped drive oscillating systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

I am currently looking at the theory of find the viscosity of and object through damped harmonic motion, and tho it can be done there is obviously a limitation with regrades to the medium. If the medium is too viscous then critical dampening will occur and we lose the ability to find the viscosity.

I was looking at the equation for motion of a driven system and was wondering if you could use a driven oscillator to work out the viscosity of a more viscous medium.

Comment: No I do mean critically damped. So with a under damped system you get an exponential decay, and I was just wondering if you could take a critically damped system and turn into a under damped system

Comment: Yes sorry, I have now rephrased the question more fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to $m \ddot{x} + k x + c \dot{x} = 0$ can be characterized with the following parameter substitutions

- $ k = m \omega_n^2 $
- $ c =2 \zeta m \omega_n $

> <sub>Where $\omega_n$ is the natural frequency of the system, and $\zeta$ the damping ratio. When $\zeta=1$ the system is critically damped when over 1 it is overdamped and under 1 it is underdamped.</sub>

The equation of motion is now

$$ \ddot{x} + \omega_n^2 x + 2 \zeta \omega_n \dot{x} = 0 $$

The solution is

$$  x(t) = \begin{cases} 
  \exp(-\omega_n \zeta t) \left( C_1 \sin (\omega t) + C_2 \cos (\omega t) \right) & \zeta \leq 1, \;\omega = \omega_n \sqrt{1+\zeta^2} \\  
  \exp(-\omega_n \zeta t) \left( C_1 \sinh (\omega t) + C_2 \cosh (\omega t) \right) & \zeta > 1, \;\omega = \omega_n \sqrt{\zeta^2-1} \end{cases} $$

So if you find the exponential decay rate $\beta = \omega_n \zeta$ experimentally, you can then solve for $\zeta$ and then for $c$ if you know the mass $m$, and the stiffness $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a mechanical system that you are using and possibly a spring-mass system?

Having made the assumption that the resistive force is proportional to the speed of the mass, the equation of motion for a system undergoing free oscillations is $m\ddot x + b\dot x + kx =0$.

If $b^2 < 4km$ the system is under damped and so will perform oscillatory motion.
If at present your system is over damped you might consider increasing the mass $m$ and $k$ which often is the spring constant to move the system into the under damped regime.

The exponential envelope will be of the form $\exp\left( -\frac {b}{2m}t\right)$

---

If the system is to be driven then the equation of motion changes to something like $m\ddot x + c \dot x + kx =F_0\cos (\omega t)$.
Having a lot of damping is good news in that the driven system will reach a steady state (constant amplitude) in a relatively short period of time.

The equation for the amplitude of the driven system $A$ as a function of driver frequency $\omega$ is quite complicated $A(\omega) = \dfrac{F_0}{\sqrt{m^2(\omega^2-\omega^2_0)+b^2\omega^2_0}}$ where $\omega_0$ is the natural frequency of the system when it is undamped.

At resonance (maximum amplitude of the driven system) $A = \dfrac {F_0}{b\omega_0}$ however it does need you to know the amplitude of the force $F_0$ produced by the driver if you want to find $b$.

Now you can get away with not knowing what $F_0$ is by taking a number of readings of amplitude of the driven system as a function of driver frequency but to eliminate $F_0$ you will have to make sure that $F_0$ does not depend on the frequency of the driver.